# Closure may outlive the function while iterating over 2D array

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<Vec<u32>` and want to iterate over every item and see if it has a bigger number on the right side. Here's my code fragment:

```rust
matrix
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(y, row)| {
        row.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .filter(|(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Unfotunately, this code returns the following error:

```rust
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `y`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:16:25
   |
16 |                 .filter(|(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `y`   - `y` is borrowed here
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
14 | /             row.iter()
15 | |                 .enumerate()
16 | |                 .filter(|(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
   | |_______________________________________________________________________________________________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `y` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
16 |                 .filter(move |(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
   |                         ++++
```

If I use `move` here, then it changes to a different error:

```rust
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `matrix`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:16:25
   |
9  |       let matrix = prepare_matrix();
   |           ------ captured outer variable
...
13 |           .flat_map(|(y, row)| {
   |  ___________________-
14 | |             row.iter()
15 | |                 .enumerate()
16 | |                 .filter(move |(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
   | |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ------
   | |                         |                                          |
   | |                         |                                          variable moved due to use in closure
   | |                         |                                          move occurs because `matrix` has type `Vec<Vec<u32>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   | |                         move out of `matrix` occurs here
17 | |         })
   | |_________- captured by this `FnMut` closure
```

I have tried to clone `matrix` and work on its clone for comparing, but it doesn't work either. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried looking inside `row` instead of going back to the full matrix? E.g. `.filter (|(x, cell)| row.iter().skip (x).any (|v| *v > *cell))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return `filter()`'s closure from `flat_map()`, but it captures `y`, which is owned by `flat_map()`, and it captures it by reference because it is `Copy`.

As always, when we want to force a closure to capture something by copy/move, we add `move` to it:

```rust
.flat_map(|(y, row)| {
    row.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter(move |(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
})
```

But now we have another problem:

```rust
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `matrix`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:10:25
   |
2  |     let matrix: Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::new();
   |         ------ captured outer variable
...
6  |         .flat_map(|(y, row)| {
   |                   ---------- captured by this `FnMut` closure
...
10 |                 .filter(move |(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ------
   |                         |                                          |
   |                         |                                          variable moved due to use in closure
   |                         |                                          move occurs because `matrix` has type `Vec<Vec<u32>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                         move out of `matrix` occurs here

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `matrix` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:6:19
   |
3  | /     matrix
4  | |         .iter()
   | |_______________- borrow of `matrix` occurs here
5  |           .enumerate()
6  |           .flat_map(|(y, row)| {
   |            -------- ^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `matrix` occurs here
   |            |
   |            borrow later used by call
...
10 |                   .filter(move |(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
   |                                                                      ------ move occurs due to use in closure
```

Because a `move` closure captures *everything* by move, it includes `matrix`. But `matrix` isn't `Copy` so we can't do that.

The way to force a `move` closure to capture something specific by reference is to add a variable containing a reference and capture it:

```rust
.flat_map(|(y, row)| {
    let matrix = &matrix;
    row.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter(move |(x, cell)| (*x..row.len()).find(|x| &matrix[y][*x] > *cell).is_none())
})
```